# Nothing happens when calling XMLHttpRequest from a custom Module Patterned Javascript library

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest

I want to build a small library for accessing my REST service.  As an experiment I decided to create a small JavaScript library to play with.

I created the following Javascript inside an html 5 page:

```
<script src="myLibrary.js"></script>
<script>
    myLib.getStuff();
</script>
```

Inside myLibrary.js I added:

```
var myLib = (function () {

    function getStuff () {

        alert("started getStuff...");

        var getRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        getRequest.open('GET', 'http://www.mozilla.org/', false);
        getRequest.send(null);

        if (getRequest.status === 200) {
            alert(request.responseText);
        }

        alert("finished getStuff...");
    }

    return {
        getStuff: getStuff
    };
})();
```

In the latest versions of FireFox and Chrome for Mac, I get the "started getStuff..." alert, then nothing after that.  It's not clear why there is no response from the request.  I thought XMLHttpRequest is supported in Chrome and FireFox.

Any thoughts on how I can get this working?

Comment: Do you get a "not allowed" error in the console? I'm guessing as you're accessing another domain.

Comment: I don't see any response or indication in the browser windows.  Where would I find the console in chrome or Firefox?

Comment: Ahhh, cool!  I get "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.mozilla.org/. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin."

Comment: I suggest reading up a little on [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). I'm not sure if there is an easy way to accomplish what you want due to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are attempting to make a Cross-Origin request, browsers by default block them for security reasons.

There are several ways to work around it. You could use a proxy on your domain and have the request pass through to the remote site.

Or if you also control the remote site (and can handle a little cross-browser hackery) you could use [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).